# Difference between "empezar" and "comenzar"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática, sinónimos

What is the difference between `empezar` and `comenzar`? Is one more formal than the other?

Comment: DerPolygott33 I'd suggest that you accept @c.p. as an answer instead of Quintrala's since the votes and comments support that one as a more precise and documented answer. Answers from us native speakers are good as reference, but a better answer is one supported by references and research.

Comment: I uphold @DGaleano 's request. Quintrala's answer is confusing and false.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

- *Empezar*, as [Eric explained](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4702/1674) is related to events. Like the beginning of history or the beginning of a work project.
- *Comenzar* is more personalized towards a subject.

Though they mean the same, we Spanish speakers tend to use each in those contexts.

Comment: *Comenzar un proyecto* is absolutely valid. Why do you state the contrary on your answer?

Comment: I am basica lly stating the most used, not the valid c.p.

Comment: The point is that, what your are writing is false: you don't say *empezar un proyecto* more often than *comenzar un proyecto* as you stated.

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely interchangeable as *Eric* states in [his answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4702/1674). I agree. However, I'd add that *empezar* is a little more common than *comenzar.* Actually [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comenzar%2F(empezar%2Bcomenzar)%2Cempezar%2F(empezar%2Bcomenzar)&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28comenzar%20/%20%28empezar%20%2B%20comenzar%29%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28empezar%20/%20%28empezar%20%2B%20comenzar%29%29%3B%2Cc0) says in written Spanish, in the last 60 years, the frequency of use has been reversed. That is:

[image]

And *comenzar* is slightly more formal. But I have no other sources than native speaker's gut.

Answer (score 6):

An existing answer, sadly the accepted one, has stated that *empezar* is more widely used than *comenzar* for things like "a project". That just [doesn't make sense](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comenzar+un+proyecto%2Cempezar+un+proyecto&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomenzar%20un%20proyecto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cempezar%20un%20proyecto%3B%2Cc0)[image]

My conclusion is not that some is used more than the other. The difference is not significant enough as for being considered as a definitive answer. That's my point.

Answer (score 3):

I use them interchangeably, but if I had to distinguish I'd say that comenzar is normally a group or event, and empezar is normally a third person.

That being said, ?puedo comenzar? is perfectly acceptable so they really are pretty interchangeable.

I speak Mexican Spanish as a caveat.

Answer (score 3):

Spanish verbs "comenzar" and "empezar" are synonyms. There is no difference between them. Also "iniciar" means the same. Do not confuse trying to state differences where they do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I guess most of the times are interchangeable, but take care with set phrases like for example

> no tengo ni para/por-dónde empezar
>
> no empieces a hacer el tonto",
>
> ¡No empieces!

In these cases, using "comenzar" instead of "empezar" would sound sort of funny.